# jar file sometimes doesn't start from network share

Tags: java, spring-boot, javafx, jar

We have a Spring Boot (v2) powered JavaFX application (v8). More user run it on Windows, from a network share, at the same time (with a batch inside `java -jar` command). Jar is created by Spring Boot Gradle plugin and runs on Oracle JRE 1.8.

It run properly for months but nowadays sometimes fails to start with error message `Error: invalid or corrupted jar file`. (Manifest file is correct.) It usually happens when:

- A user locked its PC when the application runs. After another user logs in and tries to start the same jar. This happens only on that PC which runs the jar within the locked user session. It happened on multiple machine not on only one.
- And we got a bug report: application threw a `NoClassDefFoundError` but the class is inside the jar. I think these errors have relation.

We release periodically after one or two weeks and the bug is occured in multiple versions.

I dug a lot to find a solution or a detailed description of this error, but I found nothing.

Do you have any idea?

P.S.: We use this code snippet to determine which version of jar is running:

```
        String manifestPath = classPath.substring(0, classPath.indexOf("!") + 1) +
                "/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF";
        Manifest manifest;
        manifest = new Manifest(new URL(manifestPath).openStream());
        return "v" + manifest.getMainAttributes().getValue("Manifest-Version");
```

We started to use this code near the bug is reported. It runs only on startup. I see stream is not closed manually or a try-with-resource block. Can it cause this behavior? I think not because GC will dispose the stream with an undetermined delay and between two application startup is more hours are estimated. And it is not associated with the `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not running reliably, because this is a very un-safe and un-reliable way to run an application.  Executable code should be locally on the machine executing it.

So if it has to be on a network drive for some reason then it should be copied to the server it is going to execute it and then executed there.

Since it almost sounds like you are doing some sort of build process here it would be a much better idea to use an actual build tool like Jenkins to do this.

On the log list of issues that can happen executing from a network share:

o  More than one user could try executing it at the same time causing conflicts.

o  Which ever file sharing protocol could be locking the file(s) while one looking at the file or has it selected in their network viewer

o  Different users with different permissions will get different behaviors.  If it is trying to look on the drive or config files, or write a log file(s), etc. some users permissions on that file share may not Have the needed access.

o  Network file shares are inherently un-reliable causing the file to not be accessible randomly, or to be reported as corrupted randomly.

o  Different users on different machines with different versions of the networking protocols will get different behaviors.

o  Different share protocols handle the data integrity checking differently and will cause different results.

And this could keep going for quite a while.   You get the idea.

Comment: Thanks @BrianC for your detailed description. We are waiting for the error happens again. We will try trunning from local filesystem if it happend. We thought possible the network share causes it but users wanted to run same file from network share to prevent update jar and configuration on multiple machines. If it will work we will distribute it to local machines.

Comment: It solved our problem. Thanks again @BrianC.